# Proper way of creating object using a form in its parents view?

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

Let's say I have two classes:
News (hasMany Comment)
Comment (belongsTo News)

In single news object view (news/show.gsp) I'm listing comments belonging to it after it's content.
Then I want to have a form which will allow some user (but security isn't a case here) to add new comment, and then show the same (news) view again.

Seems easy, but I couldn't find the anwser: 
What is the proper way of doing it in Grails?

Answer (score 1):

If you run `grails generate-all News` and `grails generate-all Comment` on the command-line, Grails will generate views and controller actions that allow you to CRUD each entity. If you read the generated code for the `create` and `save` actions and views of `CommentController`, that should set you straight.